# Why are my option buttons not switching up combo box text?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two option buttons that will allow a user to either search a job by it's # or it's name. [image]

so if you click the left opt button, it'll display as:

[image]

and then vice-versa:

[image]

So then I added this to populate the lists:

```
Sub Search_Reqs_Cmb_IM()
    Dim rWs As Worksheet: Set rWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Approved Roles")

    If UserForm2.optSearchReq.Value = True Then 'search by job #
        For x = 2 To rWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
            UserForm2.cmbReqNum.AddItem rWs.Cells(x, 2) & " - " & rWs.Cells(x, 13)
        Next x
    ElseIf UserForm2.optSearchJob.Value = True Then 'search by job name
        For x = 2 To rWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
            UserForm2.cmbReqNum.AddItem rWs.Cells(x, 13) & " - " & rWs.Cells(x, 2)
        Next x
    End If
End Sub
```

and then viewed code for each option button to `call Search_Reqs_Cmb_IM` each time a button is clicked.

So when I click on either one, it will always populate that no matter if I toggle between the two option buttons. I want it to switch to `job name - job number` if I click on that opt button and vice versa. How can I make sure it'll switch between the two formats?

Comment: Show us the option button code too. Avoid using underscore "_" in your procedure names because that is reserved for Events in VBA.

Comment: You need to call `.Clear` before `.AddItem` otherwise your list will just grow every time the option is selected.

Comment: yep, that was it. thanks!

Comment: Ok, I made a proper answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.Clear` before `.AddItem` otherwise your list will just grow every time the option is selected.

```
Sub Search_Reqs_Cmb_IM()
    Dim rWs As Worksheet: Set rWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Approved Roles")

    If UserForm2.optSearchReq.Value = True Then 'search by job #
        UserForm2.cmbReqNum.Clear
        For x = 2 To rWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            UserForm2.cmbReqNum.AddItem rWs.Cells(x, 2) & " - " & rWs.Cells(x, 13)
        Next x
    ElseIf UserForm2.optSearchJob.Value = True Then 'search by job name
        UserForm2.cmbReqNum.Clear
        For x = 2 To rWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            UserForm2.cmbReqNum.AddItem rWs.Cells(x, 13) & " - " & rWs.Cells(x, 2)
        Next x
    End If
End Sub
```